# Speed up text processing

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have the following script to process a file with some data: First, the header is printed to the output file. Then 60000 lines from the input are randomly picked and printed to the output (the possibility of printing the same line several times is **explicitly** wanted).

```awk
N = 60000
gawk '{if (NR < 37) print $0}' input > output
MAX=$(gawk 'END{print NR}' input)

for ((i=1; i<=$N; i++ ))
do

   declare $(gawk -v min=37 -v max=$MAX -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print "x="int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}')
   gawk -v l=$x 'NR>36 && NR==l {print $0}' input >> output

done
```

I now that this is very inefficient, so I am open to any idea how to improve the performance of this code, maybe it is possible to prevent opening and closing the input file all the time?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to first extract a 36 line header from the file called `input`, then pick 60000 random lines from the rest of the file with the possibility of randomly picking the same line multiple times. All output should go to the file named `output`.

Using `shuf` from GNU coreutils:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Fetch header (36 first lines)
head -n 36 <input >output

# Scramble the other lines and pick 60000 (allowing for repeated lines)
tail -n +37 <input | shuf -r -n 60000 >>output
```

Alternatively:

```sh
( head -n 36 <input; tail -n +37 <input | shuf -r -n 60000 ) >output
```

With GNU `head`, which leaves the input file stream at the position after the last line outputted, which means `shuf` can continue where `head` finished reading (this may not work with *some* non-GNU `head` implementations):

```sh
( head -n 36; shuf -r -n 60000 ) <input >output
```

Comment: That should work with any POSIX compliant `head` (some have been known not to be though).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know. I have a non-POSIX `head` (in this regard) on my OpenBSD system. Which is why I was careful to say that I knew it worked with at least GNU `head`.

Comment: Both GNU and OpenBSD will typically read more than needed as they read by whole chunks. Only, OpenBSD forgets to seek back to the end of the input it was meant to read (thay can only be done on seekable input, it could be done on others by reading one byte at a time or _peek_ at the input without consuming it where possible like for sockets on some systems (which is what the ksh93 `head` builtin does at least on Linux and is why it uses socketpairs instead of pipes there for pipes))

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Looking at the OpenBSD implementation, it does `getc(fp)` followed by `putchar(fp)` in a tight loop. If there is buffering, it's done by the C library.

Comment: Yes, `getc()` uses stdio which reads by whole bufs. IIRC, GNU stdio does seek back for unconsumed buffers on exit, though don't quote me on that, as it's vague memory. In any case, GNU `head` does seek back at least on GNU systems as observed with `strace()`.

Comment: See also: [Is this tail behavior in Grouping Commands specified by POSIX?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/239558)

Comment: Out of curiosity, about how long would you say this takes to run, in wallclock time?

Comment: @TankorSmash On my system, the `shuf` solution takes about 0.15 seconds. Spawning `awk` 120000 times, which is what the original code does, but without actually _doing_ anything (`awk 1 /dev/null`) takes about 10 minutes on my system.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, it works very fast compared to my gawk-command. One further question: Is there a way to make `shuf` reproducible to get the same output again in the future?

Comment: @quadrupoltensor `shuf` can take "random bytes" from a file with `--random-source=FILE`.  Giving it the same file as a source of random bytes should make it generate the same random sequence every time.